# 128 factories close down first

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

I found this problem on http://poissonlabs.com/blog/how-insurance-works.  I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

Suppose that $1000$ factories belong to an industry, and that each factory faces an independent 10% chance that they will be closed down (because of a machine failure they can't pay for).  To protect themselves, each factory buys an insurance policy, which is capitalized in such a way that it will pay for $128$ machine failures before ruin.

So, under the policy, what is the probability that a factory will be closed down because of this peril?

The article makes some observations. For "your" factory to close down,

1. your machine would have to break.
2. 128 other machines would have to break first.

I do understand all the concepts, but I was just never very good at combinatorial probability.

It does look like the number of failures is binomial.  But how do we account for the ordering?

Comment: Does every factory only have one machine and can it break down only once (for the sake of this problem)?

Comment: Yes, the article makes that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

We want the probability that at least $k=129$ out of $n=1000$ factories have a broken machine. The probability that $i$ chosen factories have a breakdown is (with $p=0.1$)
$$
p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$$
Now, there are $\binom ni$ ways to choose the $i$ factories. This gives a probability of
$$
\binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$$
Now we have to sum from $k$ to $n$ to get the probability that at least one factory closes down:
$$
P\{\text{at least one factory closes down}\} = \sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$$

Comment: Oh, I get it.  All of the orderings are equally likely, so we don't have to condition on "my" factory's place in the order.  Am I understanding that right?

Comment: @nomen, actually, I don't see why the observations you mention would be useful for this problem. If you want to know the probability of a specific factory closing, you would need some time variable I think, because otherwise you can't speak of one factory closing down before another one.

Comment: Presumably, if $n$ machines break this year, the $n!$ orders of break downs are all equally likely. My factory is last in exactly $(n - 1)!$ of those, for example.

Comment: Being that there are 1000 factories and 128 need to close down first, it is faster to do $1 -  P(k\in[0, 128])$ than to do the sum from 129 to 1000. Using a statistical package like R you would find it as `1 - pbinom(128, 1000, 0.1)` which is approximately $0.001841$